# How to save record from c# to sql database using assignment operator?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I would like to save record from assigning a value to textbox.text from a variable then will be saved the record from textbox to database. I have tried it but a garbage value always saved in the database instead of the value I assign to the textbox.

here are my line of code:

```
string r = "returned";
comboBox2 = r;

SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=**************;Initial Catalog=lights and sounds;User ID=*****;Password=********;");
MySqlConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader dr;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Update reservation_inventory Set  status= '" + comboBox2 + "' WHERE id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'  ", MySqlConnection);
dr = command.ExecuteReader();
dr.Close();
```

this is the garbage value that saved in the database:

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: returned
```

your help will be highly appreciated. thank you

Comment: pleas post your markup code.

Comment: okay. i just edited it

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer which helped you most

Comment: @user3383093 Please don't post your connection string. It's not secure for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I think **comboBox2** is a Textbox control. Then you need to set **.Text** property of your control. 
In your case you should use:

```
string r = "returned";
comboBox2.Text = r;
```

and same change in your SqlCommand

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Update reservation_inventory Set  status= '" + comboBox2.Text + "' WHERE id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'  ", MySqlConnection);
```

Comment: thank you. i tried that and the garbage value changed to:
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 2

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use

```
comboBox2.Text
```

instead of using `comboBox2`. I suppose that `comboBox2` is a TextBox. So you need to read it's Text attribute.

It's reasonable that you took

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
```

because when you try to concatenate the following strings:

```
"Update reservation_inventory Set  status= '" + 
 comboBox2 + 
"' WHERE id = '" + textBox1.Text + "'  "
```

the `ToString()` method of `comboBox2` is called. Hence you get it's type name.

Comment: thank you. i tried that and the garbage value changed to:
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 2

Comment: using combobox2.text only changed the garbage value to  System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 2

Comment: look, in order to help you, I need to see your markup language. So please post your html code to see the controls that you use. Also, please state which value you want to get from these controls and store it to the db.

Answer (score 0):

use `comboBox2.Text` (or `comboBox2.content` - depends on what kind of Control) to access the text insde the Control

if you use just `comboBox2` in a string variable c# will implicitly call the `.toString()`-Method on the Control wich returns the Name of the Control.

in this case this is "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox"

Comment: thank you. i tried that and the garbage value changed to:
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox, Items.Count: 2